# By means of what language design principle is a string instantiated either as a string or as a variable in GNU Octave?

Tags: string, function, command-line, command, octave

Having an Octave script (in the sense of dynamic languages [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language)) `move.m` defining `function move(direction)`, it can be invoked from another script (alternatively from the command line) in different ways: `move left`, `move('left')` or `move(left)`. While the first two will instantiate `direction` with the string `'left'`, the last one will consider `left` as a variable.

The question is about the formal principle in language definition behind this. I understand that in the first mode, the script is invoked as a command, considering that the rest of the command line is just data, not variables (pretty much as in a Linux prompt); while in the last two it is called as a function, interpreting what follows (between parenthesis) as either data or variables. If this is a general design criteria among scripting languages, what is the principle behind it?

Comment: Your question is either confusing / poorly written, or you're confusing a few concepts. Might be worth putting some code to clarify. Do you have a script which defines a "runtime" function? What is the script's name? Does it contain other statements other than the function definition? Is there no script and just a function file `move.m` with the function definition in it? Scripts are never invoked as 'commands / functions', per se, as they're not expected to take arguments. All functions however, can be written in 'command syntax', and any subsequent arguments are interpreted as strings.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou script name updated, but there is not much more than that. So the answer might be as simple as this: Octave provides a command syntax where arguments are interpreted as data, not variables. Just wanted to know if this aligns with a design principle. (Haven't added any code, cause it would not be relevant here.)

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying. I'll write an answer below rather than making an extended comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, this is by design, and it's syntactic sugar offered by matlab (and hence octave) for running certain functions that expect *only* string arguments. Here is the relevant section in the matlab manual: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html

I should clarify some misconceptions though. First, it's not "data" vs "variables". Any argument supplied in command syntax is simply interpreted as a string. So these two are equivalent:

```
fprintf("1")
fprintf 1
```

I.e., in `fprintf 1`, the `1` is not numeric data. It's a string.

Secondly, not all m files are "scripts". You calling your m file a script caused me some confusion. Your particular file contains a function definition and nothing else, so it's a function, 100%.

The reason this is important here, is that all functions can be called either via functional syntax or command syntax (as long as it makes sense in terms of the expected arguments being strings), whereas scripts take no arguments, so there is no functional / command syntax at play, and if you were passing 'arguments' to a script you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Please, lets elaborate a little bit more about his terminology. Firstly, as a corollary of your answer, can we state that the design principle behind this provides a language with functional or command syntax (it would be great to have a name for it). Secondly, this affects not only the way arguments are passed, but also the output, as the command syntax provides no output (e.g. `a = move left` raises an error).

Comment: And finally, concerning the `script` terminology, by scripting languages I mean a programming methodology where the program is (typically) divided into a big number of scripts, representing either functions or programs (basically, dynamic languages, question updated accordingly). Of course, in the end, all methodologies will end up with files where the programs and libraries are stored, but here it is more referred to binning functional units and storing them in scripts (small text files), so here both a function and program (non-function) is a script.

Comment: W.r.t. the 1st comment, yes (though I'd stick with the terminology used in the manual; the term "functional" tends to mean other things). The main motivation seems to be as syntactic sugar for functions that act primarily as "commands", e.g. `hold on`, `format compact`, `print -dpng out.png` etc. W.r.t the 2nd comment, in a general programming sense this could be true, but it is not for matlab / octave where a function file is _not_ a script. It is identified / loaded differently. It is different to, say, python, where functions are simply first-class objects which can be defined in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that in the first mode, the script is invoked as a command [...]

As far as Octave goes, you are better off forgetting about that distinction.  I'm not sure if a "command" ever existed but it certainly does not exist now. The command syntax is just syntactic sugar in Octave.  Makes it simpler for interactive plot adjustment since it's functions arguments mainly take strings.